# nodejs tcp file upload missing parts

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I am trying to make a server and client program just on localhost to be able to upload and list files from the server.  I have the code to upload files to the server but for some reason after the server writes the file from the client it has less bytes than the original file.

Here is the client code:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var port='3000';
var host='localhost';
var path=__dirname;

var fileUploadDir = __dirname+'/uploadfolder/';

process.stdin.resume();
var socket = net.connect(port,host);

var stdin = process.stdin;
var stdout = process.stdout;
stdout.on('data', function(d){
    console.log("d: "+d);
});

socket.on('connect',function(){
    console.log("connected to server");
    //stdin.pipe(stdout);
    stdin.pipe(socket, {end: false});
});

socket.on('data', function(data){
    var b = new Buffer(data, "utf8");
    var bStr = b.toString();

    if(bStr=="okupload"){
        console.log("uploading file");
        folderFilesUpload(socket);
    }else{
        console.log(bStr);
    }
});

socket.on('end', function(){
    socket = net.connect(port,host);
    console.log('socket ended');
});

function folderFilesUpload(socket){
 fs.readdir(fileUploadDir, function(err, results){
        if(err)
            console.log("upload to upload files");
        else{
            if(results.length > 0){
                for(var r in results){
                    var fullPath = fileUploadDir+results[r];
                    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fullPath);
                    fileStream.on('open', function(){
                        fileStream.pipe(socket);
                    });
            }
        }else{
            console.log("no files to upload");
        }
    }
});
}
```

Server Code:

```
var net=require('net');
var fs=require('fs');

var host ='localhost';
var port='3000';

var outputDir = __dirname+'/outputdir/';
var uploadState = false;

var server = net.createServer(function(conn){
    console.log('server connected');
    conn.on('data', function(data) {

        if(data == "l\n" && !uploadState){
            listFiles(conn);
        }

        if(data == "u\n"){
            console.log("switching to upload file state");
            uploadState=true;
            conn.write("okupload");
        }

        if(uploadState){
            console.log("data");
            //console.log("data: "+data);
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(outputDir+'temp');
            conn.pipe(file);
        }

    });
    conn.on('end', function(){
        uploadState = false;
        console.log('data has ended');
    });
});

server.listen(port,host, function(){
    server.on('connection', function(){
        console.log('connection made');
    });
});

function listFiles(conn){
    console.log("listing files");
    fs.readdir(outputDir, function(err, results){
        if(err){
            var b = new Buffer("error listing files", "utf8");
            conn.write(b);
        }else{
            var output = "files: \n";
            if(results !== null && results.length >0){
                for(var r in results){
                    output += results[r]+"\n";
                }
            }else{
                output += "no files.\n";
            }
            var b = new Buffer(output, "utf8");
            conn.write(b);
        }
    });  
}
```